# Authenticate GameCenter local player ALWAYS returns FALSE - SWIFT

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, game-center

I am trying to authenticate the local player in my SPRITE-KIT/SWIFT game but it always returns false, and the GameCenter sign in bubble does not come up. Here's the function I am using:

```
//initiate gamecenter
func authenticateLocalPlayer(){
    var localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(viewController, error) -> Void in

        if (viewController != nil) {
            //These 2 lines are the only parts that have been changed
            let vc: UIViewController = self.view!.window!.rootViewController!
            vc.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else {
            println((GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated))
        }
    }
}
```

When i first used this code, it worked and the GameCenter sign in came up. I didn't change anything at all and it just stopped working for some reason and now always returns FALSE so the player doesn't get signed in. Help will be much appreciated. Thank You!!